# Sphinx timestamp functions

Tags: mysql, sphinx

In Mysql you can use the function timestampdiff. In Sphinx a similar function doesnt seem to exist, right?
What I need is to get the number of days from day1 to day2. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps in sphinx (Assuming you just storing a unix timestamp in a sphinx attribute - which is an integer) are just a number of seconds since a fixed point,

so can be used directly in a mathematical expression....

```
days = (tsone-tstwo)/(60*60*24)
```